# How to get and output a pid of a 2nd terminal tab on 1st terminal tab?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, pid

The question is related on a Linux Mint 64, 20.x system with Cinnamon desktop

Running the follow sample code on terminal are doing the follow:

- output the pid of 1st terminal tab on 1st terminal tab
- create a 2nd terminal tabs
- output one thing on 2nd terminal tab

Sample code:

```
echo "pid von TAB1: $$"; gnome-terminal --title="Titel of 2nd TAB" --tab --active -- bash -c "sensors; read exec bash"
```

Booth terminal tabs have a own pid. This can be seen by:

```
ps ax | grep bash
```

Booth terminal tabs can be closed for testing purposes by his own pid by:

```
kill 123456
```

How to get and output a pid of a 2nd terminal tab on 1st terminal tab ?

Comment: `pgrep` can help but you always have the possibility of finding an other terminal than the one you're looking for...

Comment: @Fravadona, thats right, pgrep bash will output a list of teminal pids. So its possible to get a list before and after opening the new terminal tab. A on this way its not 100% shure to get the right pid. It can be its possible by $$ or $! ?

Comment: You can use `pgrep -P` to know the child process of a governor process which the terminal may belong to, but knowing what the tab's actual process is among the many would be difficult. This governor process can be a daemon, a singleton service, or simply a parent.

Comment: @konsolebox, thats sound intresting. A a pgrep -P $$ on first terminal tab, dont give me the pid of 2nd terminal tab or one other pid.

Comment: $$ is the PID of the shell and not a governor process. Look at the output of pstree. Maybe you'll find clues in it. Again the governor process is only theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

#### Partial solution which doing the follow:

- Output on first terminal tab, all bash related pids before opening 2nd terminal tab
- Output of the true `pid` from first terminal tab on first terminal tab
- Output of the true `pid` from second terminal tab on second terminal tab
- Output on first terminal tab, all bash related pids, after opening 2nd terminal tab

```
prep bash; echo "pid von TAB1: $$"; gnome-terminal --title="Titel of 2nd TAB" --tab --active -- bash -c 'echo $$ & sensors; read exec bash'; pgrep bash
```

The following are *not* solved by this partial solution:

- Unable to output the `pid` of second terminal tab on first terminal tab.

Answer (score 0):

#### Partial solution which doing the follow:

- output on first bash tab a list of bash related pids before opening 2nd bash tab
- output on first bash tab a list of bash related pids after opening 2nd bash tab

echo list of bash tabs before open 2nd tab; pgrep bash; gnome-terminal --title="Titel of 2nd TAB" --tab --active -- bash -c "sensors; read exec bash"; echo list of bash tabs incl. 2nd bash tab; pgrep bash

The following are not solved by this partial solution:

- how to get as a output, the pid which are on 2nd pid output, a not on first pid output